# Mongodb : Stream change

Tags: mongodb

The rc0 of mongoldb 3.6 as been released till last Friday, and I have 
tested the new feature regarding the stream change.

My tests show me that I can retrieve the inserted/updated *(did not test the replace yet)* document when the operation occurred in mongo shell.

But here is the thing: When I perform a delete operation under mongo shell, I can't retrieve the document with the same java code.

I know that the driver 3.6.0-beta2 is not ready, but I'm wondering if this should appear normal to retrieve such a thing when deleting a document.

Right now I don't see why this feature will not be available. I know also this is speculation, but just like to have your opinion about this.

Answer (score 1):

The change stream will trigger an event upon document deletion (see [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#delete-event)) but since the document is already deleted when this is trigger the result includes just the document id/key but no field data.